# Как создать репозиторий на github из svn?

Tags: git, svn, репозиторий

Хочу создать репозиторий вроде тех, что на гитхабе. Есть SVN. Но git clone SVN не клонирует. Как создать репозиторий?

Comment: `git init` - этой командой вы инициализируете репозиторий. Потом нужен будет доступ по `ssh` до сервера.

Comment: А если я являюсь сервером?

Comment: в папке с проектом `git init`

Comment: @Stasicheck Ну тогда делайте в корне проекта `git init`.

Comment: Репозиторий создан?
stasicheck@Stas-PC ~/svn-start $ git init
Инициализированный пустой репозиторий Git в /home/stasicheck/svn-start/.git/
stasicheck@Stas-PC ~/svn-start $

Comment: Т. е. надо сделать экспорт из svn в git? С сохранением истории?

Comment: git add test, git commit. Пишет, нечего фиксировать.

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы я мог вносить изменения в код.

Comment: @Stasicheck, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам не нужно переносить историю коммитов с SVN, то переходите в папку с кодом и создаете репозиторий следующей командой:

```
git init
```

Этим самым вы создадите пустой репозиторий и в текущей папке появляется скрытая папка `.git` После создания репозитория нужно добавить все нужные файлы и сделать первый коммит. Добавить все имеющиеся файлы и сделать коммит этими двумя командами:

```
git add -A
git commit -m "first commit"
```

Comment: Спасибо._______

Answer (score 4):

github предлагает свою [инструкцию](https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion/) (на англ.) по миграции с svn. Вкратце:

Если ваш svn доступен из открытого интернета, можно воспользоваться github'овским инструментом для импорта: [import.github.com/new](https://import.github.com/new) – там ввести URL вашего svn проекта, пункт назначения, и вперёд.

Другой вариант – инструмент [svn2git](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git), который сконвертирует локально svn репо в формат git, и останется только его запушить в github.

Comment: Я сдампил svn репозиторий к себе, по статье на хабре его "пролечил" (транк, ветки), сконвертил svn2git и запушил. Много гемора, но зато все по феншую.